# How to get an exit code outside a shellscript

Tags: shell

I try to call $? inside a script but it doesn't work as expected.

```bash
# exit_status.sh
echo $?
```

`(){return 1}; echo $?` --> 1
`(){return 1}; ./exit_status.sh` --> 0

Comment: Are you asking how to send the exit code of a script to another script? You could do that with `./exit_status.sh "$?"` and then in `exit_status.sh` you can do `echo "$1"`.

Comment: No, I don't want to explicitly send the status from a command line. I did that way firstly, but I always forget to write args. Now I want the script to work without any arguments.

Comment: Well you could also read the exit code from stdin if you do something like `echo "$?" | ./exit_status.sh`.